# How to Align children div either side of parent div, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I've got two images that need to be aligned on either side of the title, preferable on the edges of the page. I tried to use position relative but it's not responsive to other screen sizes.
Can someone show me an efficient way to do this, please?

Currently its like this, but i want the two images to be on either side of the title.

[image]

```css
title{
  width: 100%;
 


}
.web{  
  font-size: 120px;
}

.js{
  height: 230px;
  width: 240px;
  
}

.css{
  height: 230px;
  width: 440px;
 
  
}
```

```html
    <div class="intro py-3 bg-white text-center">
        <img class="js" src="images/js-flat.png" alt="js">
        <div class="title">
          <h2 class="web text-primary display-3 my-4">Wev Dev Quiz</h2>

          <img class="css" src="images/css2.png" alt="css">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Paste the CSS of your snippet in the CSS field and not above your HTML. Or at least use `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` property  in your parent div. I did some changes of your html and css codes below.

Here is the html part. I deleted the div that has a `title` class because all elements that are needed to be align should be seperated each other if you use `display:flex`

Here is the HTML and CSS codes:

```css
.intro {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center
}

.web{  
  font-size: 120px;
}

.js{
  width: 240px;
  
}

.css{
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro bg-white ">
    <img class="js" src="images/js-flat.png" alt="js">
    <h2 class="web text-primary">Wev Dev Quiz</h2>
    <img class="css" src="images/css2.png" alt="css">
</div>
```

When you use `display:flex` all items are aligned as horizontally. But we want to align them vertically. So we need to use `flex-direction:column` (its default is row). To align these items center, we also need `align-items` because this is used to align in cross axis which is perpendicular to the main axis.

Codepen: [you can check it here](https://codepen.io/yagnurl/pen/xxRgMda)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but i think I wrote my question wrong. i want the two images to be on either side of the title . sorry

Answer (score 0):

never-mind, i fixed it with:

.intro {

```
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center
```

}